# Return if function value is null

Tags: c++

I'm writing an exercise compiler, and lookup_helper(key,current) returns a pointer to some Symbol if its found in the current scope.
the for() loop is cycling through all scopes and searching for some symbol until it finds it and returns it. otherwise nullptr is returned.

```
    Symbol * lookup()
    {

     //....
     //....

    //search all scopes
    for (int i = Scopes.size(); i > 0; i--)
            {
                Scope current = Scopes[i - 1];

                if (lookup_helper(key, current)) //not good design
                    return lookup_helper(key, current); //calling second time

            }
        return nullptr; //not found
    }
```

Isn't this code calling lookup_helper() twice? once in the if() and once in the return? I have the solution to this problem, but I'm looking for a more elegant solution that calls lookup_helper only once (also I don't want to create some variable to store the return value). Maybe what I'm asking is impossible because I would have to jump into the execution of the code to determine whether or not lookup_helper returns nullptr or not.

What I would imagine elegant:(does not work like this)

```
for (int i = Scopes.size(); i > 0; i--)
        {
            Scope current = Scopes[i];

            return (ifnotnull) lookup_helper(key, current); 

        }
```

Comment: Why not use local variable ?

Comment: In OP, I say that its not something I would like to do. I'm looking for a feature of the language (something like a lambda or something) that allows it to call the function only once

Comment: In which way is the last example elegant? Still calling `lookup_helper` twice, plus checking (attempting to) twice now?

Comment: Sorry, I mistyped the last example, updated the OP~

Comment: "I don't want to create some variable to store the return value" -- Why not? What's the rationale for wanting to avoid doing this?

Comment: Maybe there is a way to capture the return value and evaluate the return right there on the spot without having to store it into a variable first. My OCD working against me is all. As I've stated in the OP, I have a working solution, but I'm just going over the edge

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With local variable in the most inner scope, you may do

```
for (int i = Scopes.size(); i > 0; i--) {
    if (auto ret = lookup_helper(key, Scopes[i])) {
        return ret;
    }
}
```

or the more traditional

```
for (int i = Scopes.size(); i > 0; i--) {
    auto ret = lookup_helper(key, Scopes[i]);
    if (ret) {
        return ret;
    }
}
```

Comment: what does that if() statement return? true if ret is not null? I like that

Comment: @user3465668 The `lookup_helper` function returns a pointer so `auto ret` is a pointer type. The `operator=` returns a reference to the modified object (i.e., a pointer). Finally, `T* ptr = nullptr; if (ptr) { ... }` illustrates why the above `if (auto ret = lookup_helper(...))` works.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, your code calls `lookup_helper` twice. Some compilers might be able to eliminate the second call, if they know that the function is "pure" (using GCC terminology). However, in C++ it is one of those "optimizations" that are better done manually and explicitly.

As for how to avoid the second call, it is typically done by storing the result in an intermediate variable before trying to analyze it

```
...
Symbol *symbol = lookup_helper(key, current);
if (symbol != nullptr)
  return symbol;
....
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes your code will call the lookup_helper twice. A simple solution is to store the result into a local variable:

```
...
for(auto & scope : Scopes) {
    auto ret = lookup_helper(key, scope);
    if(ret) return ret;
}
...
```